# How can I duplicate time atrributes in C on Linux?

Tags: c, linux

I tried to make a copy program. I made it, but it's hard to implement copying time-atrributes(access time, modify time, change time).
I thought that I can make it using st_atime, st_mtime, st_ctime of struct stat. 
But I don't know where should I use them.
Can you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define MAX_BUF 64

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buf[MAX_BUF];
    int fd, fd1, read_size, write_size;
    struct stat stat;     // struct stat variable  

    // if the number of arguments are not 3, return 0
    if(argc != 3) {
            printf("\nUSAGE: %s [old_file_name] [new_file_name]\n\n", argv[0]);
            return 0;
    }
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);   // execute an original file descriptor(read only)
    fstat(fd, &stat);       // store stats of the original file

    // execute a file descripoter to be copied
    if(0 < (fd1 = open(argv[2], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, stat.st_mode))) {

            // write data of original in copied
            while(1) {
                    read_size = read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
                    if(read_size == 0) break;
                    write_size = write(fd1, buf, read_size);
            }
    } else
            printf("\nfile name of [%s] is already exist\n\n", argv[2]);
    close(fd);
    close(fd1); // close file descriptors
```

}

Comment: The `stat` call gives you the metadata about the file you're copying *from*.  Setting the metadata on the file you're copying *to* is more complicated.  To set the mtime and atime use `utime`.  You can't set the ctime.  To set the mode use `chmod`.  To set the user and group use `chown` and `chgrp` (though these will usually not work if you're not root).  And then on some filesystems there are extended attributes, which are more complicated still.

Comment: @SteveSummit 
Thank you very muchhhhh !!!!!      I finished!!!
Frankly I used not utime but utimensat, your comment gave me a good direction. Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you're after is called [`utime()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/utime).